# Finding object transfer time using HTTP/2 with libcurl

Tags: libcurl, http2

I am wondering if there is a way to record individual downloaded object  transfer time while using HTTP/2 connection with libcurl?

Answer (score 1):

You're in charge of the write callback, so you can at the very least add your own timing using that.

The timing and speed info (CURLINFO_*_TIME, [CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD.html) etc) you can extract with [curl_easy_getinfo](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html) should also work fine for HTTP/2 as well.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any relevant example available in the libcurl website for http2?

Comment: Not for timing/speed measurements in particular, but there are a few for doing http2 transfers.

Comment: Ok, I tried to use the curl_easy_getinfo(multi_handle, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD, &bytes) just before curl_multi_cleanup(multi_handle). It obviously compiles but the result is different in each run. In my example application, which is based on http2_download example, I only maid 4 multiplexed connections.

Comment: Then you seem to be asking follow-up questions, disguised as comments here. Ask a new question or edit your question above. Also, curl_easy_getinfo does not take a multi handle as first argument.

Comment: Yes I was wrong about the argument to the curl_easy_getinfo...it is working now. Thanks. Can I just start a new question and move the ongoing question there..or there is a better idea